# 2009 Mac Install OS

Tags: imac

I have a 2009 iMac.  I recently erased the drive using disk utility, thinking I'd just download a fresh copy of the most current OS it could run.  I think it is High Sierra but I am not sure how to proceed.  The Mac will book to disk utility.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos)

Comment: The early 2009 iMac can run up to 10.11 (El Capitan), the late 2009 model supports up to 10.13 (High Sierra)

Comment: If you can still boot to the Recovery Partition, then there's an option there for installing the OS. My main concern would be the effect of heavy duty actions like erasing and installing an OS on a 12-year-old mechanical drive.